# Commits in GitKraken. Make the Summary Required

Tags: gitkraken

I'm using GitKraken to commit to a git lab setup. One of the gotchas is if you don't include a summary in the commit, the commit in gitlab is unclickable.

Is there a way in GitKraken to make the summary required so if I accidentally leave it out it stops the commit and forces me to add one?

I couldn't find one in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still couldn't find anything to make it specifically required but I have worked around this issue by creating a default commit template that has a summary.
It's a good reminder and at worst the commit is now always clickable in gitlab.

To create a commit template in gitkraken go:
File -> Preferences -> Commit Template